# Swift: The spacing between my cells in my UICollectionView is not zero

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Although I have my own custom layout, my cells still have a bit of spacing. I am trying to fit 7 items per row, but I always get six with a bunch of spacing.

Here is my layout:

```
class monthFlow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/7, height: collectionView.frame.size.height/8)
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Yet it looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. The built-in behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is to space your cells out evenly across the screen (full justification). If you don't want that, you'll have to do more than you're doing in your UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass to change the behavior - you'll need to override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`.

In fact, from the code you've shown so far, there was no need to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout in the first place; everything *you're* doing could have been done by setting properties of the layout. But to change full justification to left justification, you *do* need to subclass.

You might even consider writing your own collection view layout *not* as a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout, especially since a month layout is not a flow layout - it always consists of 7 cells across, which is not what a flow layout does. So, in a way, your mistake here was thinking you could to this without writing your own layout in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll write my own layout and not a flowLayout. Any decent tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: An absolute rock-bottom layout is easy; see my example code at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p467collectionViewLayoutFromScratchSwift/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/MyLayout.swift But things can get complicated after that...!

Comment: I combined your code with mine, and now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/lYVcJz9.png How do I change the cell width and height?

Comment: 35 days hath September...! :) Don't just copy my code: _look_ at it. It isn't intended for you to use; it's just a teaching example. You can see me setting the frame of each cell's attributes; if you don't like my frame, set your own.

Comment: I am; but I am curious as to how your calculations for width work: When I divide `width` by a larger number, the width increases.

Comment: Maybe my code doesn't work. (It looks like works, but hey, what do I know?)